# how to use StreamWriter class properly?

Tags: c#, streamwriter

I am using `StreamWriter` class for file operations, are there any problems in this code that I am not seeing?

Such as do I need to put it into a `try catch finally` block?

```
StreamWriter sr = new StreamWriter(streamFolder);
sr.Write(details);

File.SetAttributes(streamFolder, FileAttributes.Hidden);
sr.Close();
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Whats wrong with your code? If some exception will occur before you close stream, then stream will stay open, and system resources will not be released:

```
StreamWriter sr = new StreamWriter(streamFolder);
sr.Write(details);
// some exception occurs here 
File.SetAttributes(streamFolder, FileAttributes.Hidden);
sr.Close();
```

So, you need to be sure, that stream will be closed. This could be achieved by `try...finally` block:

```
StreamWriter sr = new StreamWriter(streamFolder);

try 
{
   sr.Write(details);
   // some exception occurs here 
   File.SetAttributes(streamFolder, FileAttributes.Hidden);
}
finally
{
   sr.Close();
}
```

But StreamWriter implements [IDisposable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aax125c9) interface, so you can let C# compiler do it automatically for you by wrapping writer usage into `using` block:

```
using(StreamWriter sr = new StreamWriter(streamFolder)) 
{
   sr.Write(details);
   // some exception occurs here 
   File.SetAttributes(streamFolder, FileAttributes.Hidden);
}
```

This code will be compiled as:

```
StreamWriter sr = new StreamWriter(streamFolder);

try 
{
   sr.Write(details);
   // some exception occurs here 
   File.SetAttributes(streamFolder, FileAttributes.Hidden);
}
finally
{
   if (sr != null)
      sr.Dispose();
}
```

The only difference between manual implementation is null-check and method `Dispose` is called instead of `Close`. But actually when you call `Close()` or `Dispose()` same code will be executed:

```
this.Dispose(true);
GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
```

You can read more on [Dispose method implementation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fs2xkftw).

Answer (score 7):

You should probably use a using statement:

```
using (StreamWriter sr = new StreamWriter(streamFolder))
{
    sr.Write(details);
    File.SetAttributes(streamFolder, FileAttributes.Hidden);
}
```

At the end of the using block, the StreamWriter.Dispose will be called, whether there was an exception or the code ran successfully.

Comment: is there any perfomance impacts here? i mean comparing .close() and using , because both are garbage collector?

Comment: No, it's about the same as wrapping the whole code in a try ... finally and call Dispose in the finally block.

Comment: well there is the implication that it can throw an exception on creation(file access violation, whatever).

so you still need the try catch anyways. using is fine for something but not a catch all for other stuff.

Answer (score 5):

You want to use:

```
  using (StreamWriter sr = new StreamWriter(streamFolder))
  {
      sr.Write(details); 

      File.SetAttributes(streamFolder, FileAttributes.Hidden); 
  }
```

You don't need the `Close`.

Comment: is there any perfomance impacts here? i mean comparing .close() and using , because both are garbage collector

Comment: @vettori There's no performance impact; the `using` statement is about ensuring that the StreamWriter is properly closed even if an exception is thrown within the `using`.

Comment: By using "using" the object gets disposed automatically after the context

Answer (score 5):

Wrap it in a `using` block

```
using(StreamWriter sr = new StreamWriter(streamFolder))
{
      sr.Write(details);
      File.SetAttributes(streamFolder, FileAttributes.Hidden);
}
```

Make sure your naming is good, so `streamFolder` should probably be an `fName`. You can also put this code into try-catch-finally, if you feel you can handle some IO (or other) exceptions:

```
StreamWriter sr;
try
{
    sr = new StreamWriter(streamFolder);
    sr.Write(details);
    File.SetAttributes(streamFolder, FileAttributes.Hidden);
}
catch(IOException ex)
{
    //handling IO
}
finally
{
    if (sr != null)
        sr.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: second approch will increase lines of code, i am looking an optimized code

Comment: @vettori you should be aware that `using` is translated into `try-finally` by the compiler. So you still get this code. I would be cautious doing any micro optimisation.

Comment: @oleksii,  is it? on unity at least the file exception is not caught.

Answer (score -3):

System.IO.StreamWriter is a System.IDisposable

You have to dispose it. And why do you close something you don't open ?

Comment: Yes it opens it, so it must close it. Don't close something you don't open, it's a bad habit.

Comment: What is "it"? Do you mean that the StreamWriter must close itself?

Comment: I'm sure that it call method "Close" during dispose.Yes if an object is capable of autoopen, it is capable of autoclose.

Comment: I know this is kind of old, but the StreamWriter won't close itself unless you're either wrapping it in a `using` statement, or calling StreamWriter.Close on it.  I'm not sure what user1485585 is referring to by "autoclose".